Is it possible to push git sparse-checkout settings, so every team member has the same settings by default?
I am currently introducing a library from repository "B" to repository "A" as a submodule.
The Repository "B" referred to as a submodule includes additional test code and scripts which should not be part of repository "A".
I successfully used sparse-checkout locally to only see 1 desired folder from repository "B" in the Repository "A" checkout.
To keep my project in repository "A" identical for all team members, I am looking for a way to apply the same sparse-checkout settings to all of them.
So far I found no way to push anything about the settings into repository "A", so I am asking myself if there are other means to reach this goal.
Thank you in advance for your help.

You can create and push a script that recreates configuration. But everyone should get and execute the script. There is no way in Git to force-push configuration.
